# audit: type=1400, apparmor='denied'

Tags: drivers, kernel, apparmor, dmesg

I have written a program .c and Makefile. Makefile created a file .ko, afer this I used the next commands:

```
sudo insmod filename.ko 
sudo sysctl kernel.dmesg_restrict=0
dmesg | tail
```

As result, I recieved such strings:

```
[169396.221688] audit: type=1400 audit(1697726842.148:30133473): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" class="ptrace" profile="snap.python-ai-toolkit.jupyter" pid=1133 comm="python3" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined" 

[169396.221693] audit: type=1400 audit(1697726842.148:30133474): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" class="ptrace" profile="snap.python-ai-toolkit.jupyter" pid=1133 comm="python3" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined" 

[169396.221695] audit: type=1400 audit(1697726842.148:30133475): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" class="ptrace" profile="snap.python-ai-toolkit.jupyter" pid=1133 comm="python3" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined" 

[169396.221706] audit: type=1400 audit(1697726842.148:30133476): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" class="ptrace" profile="snap.python-ai-toolkit.jupyter" pid=1133 comm="python3" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined" 

[169396.221745] audit: type=1400 audit(1697726842.148:30133477): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" class="ptrace" profile="snap.python-ai-toolkit.jupyter" pid=1133 comm="python3" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined" 

[169396.221760] audit: type=1400 audit(1697726842.148:30133478): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" class="ptrace" profile="snap.python-ai-toolkit.jupyter" pid=1133 comm="python3" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"

[169396.221881] audit: type=1400 audit(1697726842.148:30133479): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" class="ptrace" profile="snap.python-ai-toolkit.jupyter" pid=1133 comm="python3" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined" 

[169396.221890] audit: type=1400 audit(1697726842.148:30133480): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" class="ptrace" profile="snap.python-ai-toolkit.jupyter" pid=1133 comm="python3" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined" 

[169396.221903] audit: type=1400 audit(1697726842.148:30133481): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" class="ptrace" profile="snap.python-ai-toolkit.jupyter" pid=1133 comm="python3" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined" 

[169396.221917] audit: type=1400 audit(1697726842.148:30133482): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" class="ptrace" profile="snap.python-ai-toolkit.jupyter" pid=1133 comm="python3" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
```

I didn't manage fix those. I have found out the problem have nothing with my codes. I have Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. What should I do?

I tried that my program responds the command: dmesg | tail

Answer (score 2):

> What should I do?

**Nothing.**  This is standard behavior when a snapped (SANDBOXED!) toolkit runs and tries to access a function call it is not permitted to.

What you're seeing is that the Python AI Toolkit snap's jupyter components are trying to call `ptrace` and is not permitted to.  `ptrace` is a system call which does this (from manpages):

```
The ptrace() system call provides a means by which one process
(the "tracer") may observe and control the execution of another
process (the "tracee"), and examine and change the tracee's
memory and registers.  It is primarily used to implement
breakpoint debugging and system call tracing.
```

By default, AppArmor profiles for your snap are set to deny ptrace.  This is **standard behavior** and you don't have to do **anything** about these notices.

These also have nothing to do with your C code you're working with.

---

Note that this has **absolutely nothing** to do with `dmesg` and *everything* to do with what's running on the system you are executing `dmesg` on.  `dmesg` is just a log reader/displayer.  It isn't generating this output - it's simply replaying whats in the boot and kernel logs.

You see different output on different systems and hardware **because they are all different and run different software**.  That's why you see different output on different systems.

Comment: Ok, but why does 'dmesg' work correctly on other hardware? Command and program 'dmesg' exists for linux. It can not be that it doesn't work anyone machine with linux.

Comment: @Shwarz I'm confused by your question?  `dmesg` isnt triggering that message.  This system has other software running on it that generates that output to the kernel log, which is what `dmesg` reads from.  The only relation that dmesg has in this case is its reading syslogs just like on other systems.  *This* particular system is running things that the others arent, so you get completely different output.